# How to stop Mountain Lion to stop shutting down and closing all my applications?

Tags: macos

I tried to look up related problems with this, but I haven't been able to find a solution. After leaving my computer on, charged, and step away, sometimes it logs my account off. When I come back, log on, all my applications have been turned off. I have adjusted the settings under "Energy Saver" and allow the computer a longer sleep time, but that doesn't seem to work.

OS X Version 10.8.2
Any suggestions?

Comment: What model / how old is your Mac?

Comment: Mountain Lion has some new auto-terminate function for apps, which COULD explain that part.  But, the auto-log-off is the strange part to me.  Have you checked the Console Log?

Answer (score 1):

When you say it "logs your account off" do you mean that you have to enter your password?

My guess is that someone has set [Security & Privacy settings](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH3956) to require a login password after sleep or screen saver begins. Go to Apple menu > System Preferences, click Security & Privacy, and then click General to see.

Comment: This would not lead to applications being quit when the computer locks.

Comment: @octern true, but it's not guaranteed the two symptoms are related…

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to **System Preferences** → **Security & Privacy**.
2. Unlock the preference pane.
3. Click **Advanced**.
4. Uncheck the **Log out after *?* minutes of inactivity** or change the time.